# Can I turn off this Necromancer visual effect?

Tags: diablo-iv

I was in a team with a Necromancer and one the skills was to create a patch of black smoke. However this skill seems to just obscure everything! My character, my loot, enemies and even chests.

This is what it looks like.

[image: Radiant chest obscured by a circular black smoke patch]

Is there a setting I can use to disable other players effects so my gameplay is not impacted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

As of 1.0.3, this appears to have been patched according to [this site](https://www.gamesradar.com/diablo-4-necromancer-corpse-explosions-have-finally-been-fixed-so-you-can-actually-see-the-game/).

---

**Original answer**:

As of now, no, but it seems like an upcoming patch may change this.  A [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/141hyx1/blighted_corpse_explosion_impossible_to_see/) with a reply from a developer:

> We have a fix for this in a patch later this month (requires a bit of a larger patch to fix this)